# getting this error "ImportError: dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version" ruuning IBridgePY

Tags: python, macos, python-dateutil

when I run the RUN_ME.py file from Ibridgepy folder on python 2.7 on Mac OS X ver 10.9.5 terminal, I get this error `ImportError: dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version`

I have installed `dateutil` 2.5.0 using `pip install python-dateutil==2.5.0`, still the same error.

Pls help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470373/dateutil-2-5-0-is-the-minimum-required-version)

Comment: no. I installed dateutil 2.5.0 still getting this error

Comment: Have you tried other answers there?